# Why is my Google App Engine app accruing such a large bill so quickly?

Tags: reactjs, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I deployed my own personal website to Google Cloud's App Engine last week, and since then it has built up around a $12 bill. But there would be very few if any people actually visiting my site, as I'm really the only one who knows about it.

It is a basic React app that uses React Router to display three different pages. I can't imagine the code that I used in the app is so complex that it's causing the bill to stack up, because the code is very basic.

The logging shows health, liveness and readiness checks being completed on the app constantly, is this something that would add to the cost of the app?

[image]

I'm relatively new to deploying apps on the cloud, is there anything I can do to reduce the cost of having this app deployed?

Comment: Check and close the unnecessary logs and cloud storage it used.

Answer (score 0):

1. Is this Flex or Standard? A Flex instance never goes down to 0 (which means you're being billed) whereas a Standard instance goes to 0 when there's no traffic (which means no billing for that period).
2. Do you have multiple versions of your App running? When deploying, if you do not specify a version number, gcloud will generate a version number for you. This means that multiple deployments might lead to you having multiple versions and if you do not delete them or force traffic to be migrated to the newer versions, you might end up with multiple versions running and thus increasing your bill. You should check the number of versions you have by going to your console and delete any one you don't need.
3. Are you using manual scaling or what type of settings do you h
4. Check out the following tips (short twitter threads from our account) to see if the tips will help - [tip 1](https://twitter.com/GUI_4_GAE/status/1465787197571813376), [tip 2](https://twitter.com/GUI_4_GAE/status/1458961483249848327)